# Change signature in Outlook Web (OWA) with Powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook, signature, outlook-web-app

Until now, I was using `Set-MailboxMessageConfiguration` in PowerShell to change OWA's signatures and it worked perfectly. No permission problems, no configuration problems, nothing.

Today, I was trying to update my signature with PowerShell but nothing happened, the signature in the browser is not changed at all.

[image: Signature OWA]

But if I use `Get-MailboxMessageConfiguration`, the new signature is there:

[image: Signature PowerShell]

I can see that now, it's possible to manage multiples signatures in OWA. But I can't find find any information about that. So, how I can modify the already existing signature? Or, how I can create a new signature?

----- Update 01/11/2021

It's a new feature that is not available for everyone yet. My company's O365 account has it, but my student (also 0365) and classic Outlook account doesn't.

So a third option is: How I can turn off this feature?

----- Update 01/11/2021

Still no defenitive solution.
There're some workarounds that may work. Here's the github issue (opened by @Lee) and the Microsoft's Tech Community discussion:

- https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/office-docs-powershell/issues/8537
- https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-powershell/cant-no-longer-change-owa-s-signature/m-p/2907053

Comment: This may also be affecting us. Eagerly awaiting a response from someone who knows.

Comment: Did you find this documented anywhere? Even in their other release channels?

Comment: I have found, some mentions in the <<Resolved issues>> section to "Multiples signatures" but is not clear if it's for Outlook web or Outlook Windows/MacOS, everthing is under O365.

Comment: Which "Resolved issues" section? I have searched the release notes on all the update channels (including Beta and "Preview") and haven't seen any mention of this.

Comment: I forgot to paste the link, here it is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/officeupdates/monthly-channel-archived#outlook , but i'm not sure that we're talking about the same channel

Comment: Any updates? You can see the documentation issue I reported here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/office-docs-powershell/issues/8537

Comment: Nope, there aren't any updates. It seems that the others cmdlet's parameters don't work either (like -IsDarkModeTheme), so I assume that the entire cmdlet is not working with an apparently new version of Outlook Web UI.

Comment: I suggest you also open a support ticket (we have too) as Chris Davis from MSFT suggested on my issue here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/office-docs-powershell/issues/8537#issuecomment-962059190

Comment: I landed here because I noticed the same problem.
I just opened a ticket with the support

Comment: this is definitely related to the new "roaming"/multiple signatures released in OWA.  I've noticed that if a user has never had a signature applied before that the cmdlet still functions as previous, but as soon as they've either had one set by the existing cmdlet, or created manually by the user, this cmdlet now seems to have no effect.  After spending a long time on remote session with microsoft support, I can confirm that even resetting a user's settings back to default, the cmdlet still does nothing. I do not think we will get resolution until microsoft release a new cmdlet/graph-api.

Comment: i'll also add that, at least in my org, this issue doesn't seem to affect group/shared mailboxes because they don't have the new roaming thing active in their UI settings as of yet.

Answer (score 2):

Answering the question relating to your third option "How can I turn off this feature," I opened a support ticket with Microsft for my tenant and they rolled this back for us for now.  It took a few weeks to finally get sorted but we can now successfully use this command to set outlook web signatures.  Our users no longer see the option to add multiple signatures on the web version.

In the final response, they mentioned that there may be a graph solution in the works for editing the multiple roaming signatures but couldn't offer an ETA.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. Someone already mentioned this solution in the Microsoft's Tech Community discussion: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-powershell/cant-no-longer-change-owa-s-signature/m-p/3001696/highlight/true#M3307 
But sadly, it only worked temporaly, the feature came back with a new version.
The best thing to do is open a support ticket with Microsoft (like you did)